# Reading text file line by line and entering it into another application

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x

Suppose I have a text file containing lines of data. I would like to be able to read each line of this file into memory, and then enter it into another application.

For example, let's say I have a text file containing different numbers. I also have a calculator application open. I would like to be able to create a program that reads each number from the text file and remembers it, and then enters the number into the calculator application, pressing + after each number.

I've done a bit of Python 3 programming, but nothing this complicated. I'm guessing cursors would be involved, and also loops, but the specifics (even where to start) are what I need help with.

Is this possible?

Comment: You're probably going to have to break this down into smaller chunks to get the help you want. How you pass data to this external program is very dependent on a number of factors and may be your biggest hurdle. You should look at [the Python file i/o docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) for an idea of how to read the numbers from a file and store them in some data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't precise enough. What is your platform and what kind of application are you thinking of. What you ask is very easy as long as you can feed data on the "standard input" of a program, which is easy to do on Linux/Unix systems with "pipes". See here: http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html
But you have to give more details.

Comment: I used the calculator example for simplicity's sake. What this is actually for is a library, using their integrated library system (ILS). It would be a program to allow them to do batch processes, like check in or inventory multiple items. The library has portable barcode scanners, which staff use to scan large numbers of items, which are saved to a text file. I would like to be able to read that file into the ILS and perform some function. The library is using Windows boxes, and the ILS is Java-based. There is no direct access to the underlying db, so the staff interface needs to be used.

Comment: OK. You should still have a look at the link I gave previously. I see several option. If the java-based application can be driven with no graphical interface, it should be rather easy to start it from python with relevant parameters for performing the task. If the java application can't be driven this way, maybe it can run permanently with some remote/client-server/callback features?